# Fira Sans math companion

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts

What math font is a good match to Fira Sans to use in Metropolis Beamer  presentations? STIX Two looks pretty ugly in the combination, imho.

Comment: `\usepackage{newtxsf}`, perhaps

Comment: Take a look at the [README.md](https://github.com/bBoxType/FiraGO/blob/master/README.md) for the recently released [FiraGO](https://bboxtype.com/typefaces/FiraGO/#!layout=specimen) extension to Fira. Under “Future prospect” is listed the possibility of math, followed by an invitation to provide funding or expert consultancy. This site has users whose expertise would be most helpful, so someday there may be a perfect answer to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403734/beamer-metropolis-theme-recommend-a-math-font-that-matches-with-fira

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beamer metropolis theme, recommend a math font that matches with Fira](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403734/beamer-metropolis-theme-recommend-a-math-font-that-matches-with-fira)

Comment: An appropriate matching font is [Fira Math](https://github.com/Stone-Zeng/FiraMath)